# Python Tkinter how to edit variables of a script in a txt document?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm trying to figure out how I can open a txt file that contains a script and edit all of the variables inside the `if not testfolder.filter` loop in the txt file. I'm using tkinter as GUI and I have some entry fields that I want to use to replace those variables and save the txt file after pressing the button called **Add Alert**

The **script.txt** I want to update:

```
from exchangelib import Credentials, Account, UTC_NOW,  EWSTimeZone, EWSDateTime, EWSDate, Q
from collections import defaultdict
from datetime import timedelta, datetime
from kayako import KayakoAPI
from kayako import Department, TicketCount, TicketStatus, TicketPriority, TicketType, TicketNote, TicketAttachment, Ticket




#Kayako RESTAPI forbindelse
API_URL = 'https://hidden.com/api/index.php'
API_KEY = 'hidden'
SECRET_KEY = 'hidden'
api = KayakoAPI(API_URL, API_KEY, SECRET_KEY)


credentials = Credentials('hidden@hidden.com', 'hidden')
a = Account('hidden@hidden.com', credentials=credentials, autodiscover=True)

testfolder = a.public_folders_root / 'Hidden' / 'status@hidden.com'

since = UTC_NOW() - timedelta(hours=24)

high = api.first(TicketPriority, title="High")
openTicket = api.first(TicketStatus, title="Open")
task = api.first(TicketType, title="Task")
departmentid = 5



if not testfolder.filter(subject__icontains=Subj, datetime_received__gt=since, sender=EmailAdr).exists():
    ticket = api.create(Ticket, tickettypeid=task.id, ticketstatusid=openTicket.id, ticketpriorityid=high.id, departmentid=departmentid, userid="unassigned")
    ticket.subject = TicketSubj
    ticket.fullname = TicketName
    ticket.email = TicketEmail
    ticket.contents = TicketBody
    ticket.add()
    print('Log mangler! Opretter kayako ticket....')
else:
    print('Log er fundet.')
```

**My tkinter .py script**

```
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()

Timer = 0
timer1 = int(Timer)
EmailAdr = StringVar()
Subj = StringVar()
TicketSubj = StringVar()
TicketName = StringVar()
TicketEmail = StringVar()
TicketBody = StringVar()

root.geometry("400x250")  

e1 = Entry(root, textvariable=Subj)
e1.grid()
e2 = Entry(root, textvariable=EmailAdr)
e2.grid()
e3 = Entry(root)
e3.grid()
e4 = Entry(root, textvariable=TicketSubj)
e4.grid()
e5 = Entry(root, textvariable=TicketName)
e5.grid()
e6 = Entry(root, textvariable=TicketEmail)
e6.grid()
e7 = Entry(root, textvariable=TicketBody)
e7.grid()

def func1():
    global Subj
    Subj = e1.get()

def func2():
    global EmailAdr
    EmailAdr = e2.get()

def func3():
    global Timer
    Timer = e3.get()

def func4():
    global TicketSubj
    TicketSubj = e4.get()

def func5():
    global TicketName
    TicketName = e5.get()

def func6():
    global TicketEmail
    TicketEmail = e6.get()

def func7():
    global TicketBody
    TicketBody = e7.get()

def demAlle():
    func1()
    func2()
    func3()
    func4()
    func5()
    func6()
    func7()



aButton = Button(root, text="Add Alert", command=demAlle)
aButton.grid()


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to associate the Entrys with a variable. If you are just going to read them once its not necessary. Also I added a column with labels to see what field I'm working with.

You can make the substitutions in many ways, depending on how the "script.txt" can vary. I have assumed it may change and first find the first line of the if statement.

Assuming the if statement and the following lines will always stay in the same order I'm substituting the fields according to the Entrys, but only if something is entered into the Entry.

When working with the file I first read it into a list of rows as this is easy to work with. After processing I write the file with the substitutions (but with the name "new_script.txt". I'm assuming you use Utf-8 encoding, otherwise change this to your preferred encoding.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x250")

Label(root, text='Subj:').grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='w')
Subj_entry = Entry(root)
Subj_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)
Label(root, text='EmailAdr:').grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='w')
EmailAdr_entry = Entry(root)
EmailAdr_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)
Label(root, text='TicketSubj:').grid(row=3, column=0, sticky='w')
TicketSubj_entry = Entry(root)
TicketSubj_entry.grid(row=3, column=1)
Label(root, text='TicketName:').grid(row=4, column=0, sticky='w')
TicketName_entry = Entry(root)
TicketName_entry.grid(row=4, column=1)
Label(root, text='TicketEmail:').grid(row=5, column=0, sticky='w')
TicketEmail_entry = Entry(root)
TicketEmail_entry.grid(row=5, column=1)
Label(root, text='TicketBody:').grid(row=6, column=0, sticky='w')
TicketBody_entry = Entry(root)
TicketBody_entry.grid(row=6, column=1)

def demAlle():
    # Read from Entries
    Subj = Subj_entry.get()
    EmailAdr = EmailAdr_entry.get()
    TicketSubj = TicketSubj_entry.get()
    TicketName = TicketName_entry.get()
    TicketEmail = TicketEmail_entry.get()
    TicketBody = TicketBody_entry.get()
    # Read file into a list of rows which is easy to work with
    with open('script.txt', encoding='utf-8') as script:
        rows = script.readlines()
    # Find the place where you want to alter the code
    for index, row in enumerate(rows):
        if row.startswith('if not testfolder.'):
            break
    # Altering lines; this can be done in many ways...
    if Subj != '':          # Check if field is empty
        rows[index] = rows[index].replace('Subj', Subj)
    if EmailAdr != '':
        rows[index] = rows[index].replace('EmailAdr', EmailAdr)
    if TicketSubj != '':
        rows[index+2] = rows[index+2][:21] + TicketSubj + '\n'
    if TicketName != '':
        rows[index+3] = rows[index+3][:22] + TicketName + '\n'
    if TicketEmail != '':
        rows[index+4] = rows[index+4][:19] + TicketEmail + '\n'
    if TicketBody != '':
        rows[index+5] = rows[index+5][:22] + TicketBody + '\n'
    # Open file and write the new contents
    with open('new_script.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as script:
        for row in rows:
            script.write(row)

aButton = Button(root, text="Add Alert", command=demAlle)
aButton.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works perfectly - I just have to figure out how you did this(by myself ofc) My next step would be to have a button that adds another loop, where I can add custom variables again, but I have to see how!